What could happen if I sell a Put option?
I understand selling a covered call, which I have done. If it was in-the-money (ITM) at expiration, I was assigned and my shares were sold.  If out-of-the-money (OTM), then my short call expired. I've never been assigned when the option was OTM although I know it could happen (American options).
I have never sold a cash covered put. My understanding is that if assigned, I'd have to buy 100 shares at the strike price by the expiration date. I'm wondering if there is anything different involved and I'm trying to avoid the surprise of "ooh I didn't know that could happen!".
I plan to sell a $140 strike put for $1.00 ($100 total premium) on stock ABC which is currently $150. It expires in 5 days.  If ABC is at or above $140 at expiration, then I won't have to buy 100 shares of the stock at $140.  If ABC is below $140 then I'll be assigned and I'll have to buy 100 shares at $140. Either way I keep the $100. Can anything else happen?

Your understanding of selling a cash covered put is correct. Be aware that covered calls and short puts with the same terms are synthetically equivalent and have the same risk and reward. For example, owning the stock and selling an Oct 25th $140 call (a covered call) is the same as just selling the October 28th $140 put.

If you sell a put and do not close out your position (buy an offsetting put) before expiry, either the option will be exercised or it won't (I'm ignoring edge cases about expiring close to the strike).
If it is not exercised, nothing happens. You keep the premium.
If it is exercised, then you are obligated to buy stock from them at the strike price. That might result in a negative cash balance, which you could resolve by simply selling the stock that you bought at current market price.
There may be some eccentricities in resolution that I am missing, but essentially you are obligated to buy at the strike price, and can sell at the market price, which would result in a loss that you would need to account for (likely through your margin account).

This also means that in theory you could be forced to buy a stock at 140 that now trades at or just above 0. There is a limit to your loss but it can be significant.

True, and it's worse for calls - the potential loss is theoretically unlimited.

Pin risk (what you called edge cases) only relates to whether or not the trader who is short the contract does or does not want to be assigned.  It does not alter the fact that the option is either exercised or it expires.
